# Why ListView crashes if it's empty?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

In my app i have a listView:

```
lv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listOfShifts);
```

and when i setAdapter :

```
adapter = new ExpandableListCustom(getActivity(), fullList,temp);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it crashes but if the "fullList and the temp" are not empty it's working fine..
How can get over the crashing and if the List are empty, nothing on the screen and not crashing..

//ExpandableListCustom.class:

```
private Context context;
    private HashMap<ArrayList<ClockModel>,ArrayList<ClockModel> > fullList; //Headers
    ArrayList<ClockModel> child; //data

    public ExpandableListCustom(Context context,
            HashMap<ArrayList<ClockModel>, ArrayList<ClockModel>> fullList,
            ArrayList<ClockModel> child) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.fullList = fullList;
        this.child = child;
        clockSet = new Clock();
    }
```

This is how i get the values to the adapter

```
hand = new DbHandler(getActivity());
        fullList = new HashMap<ArrayList<ClockModel>, ArrayList<ClockModel>>();
         temp = new ArrayList<ClockModel>();
     ArrayList<ClockModel> child = new ArrayList<ClockModel>();
    child = hand.getDay(workName);

    for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++) {

        if(child.get(i).getDateMonth() == month){
        ClockModel m1 = new ClockModel(
                child.get(i).getId(),
                child.get(i).getDateDay(), 
                child.get(i).getDateMonth(),
                child.get(i).getDateYear(),
                child.get(i).getEnterHour(), 
                child.get(i).getBasicSec(), 
                child.get(i).getExtra0(),
                child.get(i).getExtra1(), 
                child.get(i).getExtra2());
                temp.add(m1);       
                fullList.put(temp, temp);
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
8-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at com.bib.workclocks.adapters.ExpandableListCustom.getGroupCount(ExpandableListCustom.java:197)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getCount(ExpandableListConnector.java:399)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:470)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:599)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at com.bibas.workclocks.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.java:55)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2187)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1350)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1533)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6355)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
08-22 20:51:06.596: E/AndroidRuntime(3448):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it crashes here:

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    if(fullList != null){
    return this.fullList.get(child).size();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: post the error and post your adapter

Comment: indicate line 197 @ ExpandableListCustom? did you initialize lists on Activity class?

Comment: Yes..and then it's works but i want to show empty list too

Comment: you can initialize like fullList = new ArrayLi... and temp = new ArrayL....., if you don't put any thing on that you can have empty Expandable list

Comment: Take a look to my edited question i added how i initialized . i set the list by "month" but if month are not exists i want an empty list

Comment: in `groupCount` and `childCount` check that your list is not null, if is null return 0 on those

Comment: Look above i edited my question and added from where the crashing..

Comment: why you use child in getGroupCount? you need change `return this.fullList.get(child).size();` to return `this.fullList.size();`

Comment: Beacuse it's my first time im using BaseExpandableListAdapter. )  thank you now it's work!!!!!

Comment: I can using BaseExpandableListAdapter with only one ArrayList? without hashMap?

Comment: you can use List<List<>> instead of hashMap, working with just one ArrayList depends on your model, you can,

Comment: So i did the long way :/?

Comment: no, you work good, keep going if you not have a problem with hashMap,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set adapter after checking `null` value of those lists

```
if(fullList != null && temp != null) {
   adapter = new ExpandableListCustom(getActivity(), fullList,temp);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

if you want to show empty list then create `fullList's` and `temp's` object inside `onCreateView(...)` before setting adapter.

Comment: Thanks but i have a spinner that control the data on the list. sometimes the list null and some time full..

Comment: change return fullList.size();